# Why does dpkg --list no longer show all installed programs?

Tags: command-line, apt, dpkg

I recently tried to install GIMP (photo-editor) using the terminal and I think it required me to install `flatpak`, which I don't really understand and shouldn't have installed it I guess, because now I can't do what I could before. I have since uninstalled `flatpak`, but still have same problem.

Earlier, when I was using `dpkg --list` to get the name of a program I wanted to uninstall, I could see a full list of all installed programs. Now I just get this weird list that doesn't look like programs, and it starts in alphabetical order but only starting at the letter "L", e.g.:

```
libgphoto2-6:a 2.5.16-2     amd64        gphoto2 digital camera library
```

is the first entry. And then:

```
zlib1g:amd64   1:1.2.11.dfs amd64        compression library - runtime
```

is the last entry.

It doesn't seem to be listing programs. Like, I have `clementine` installed and its no longer listed with that command. I am so confused.

To give another example, I installed and uninstalled a media player successfully earlier today using the terminal, using `dpkg --list` to determine said program's name. I can no longer see any real programs using this or similar commands I have found here.

EDIT: `apt list --installed` gives the same stupid incorrect list.

Maybe it's showing libraries instead of programs now??

Comment: my `dpkg --list` seems to work ok. What version do you have? Mine is: `$ apt list dpkg
Listing... Done
dpkg/xenial-updates,now 1.18.4ubuntu1.5 amd64 [installed]
N: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it`

Comment: I'm using Xubuntu. I typed the command you put there and it says my version is 1.19.0.5ubuntu2.1

I'm not sure my version is the problem. I think something bad happened when I tried to manually install gimp (flatpak?) because the dpkg --list thing worked before I did that.

Comment: Probably you want to use `snap list`? This would work for snaps. Snaps and flatpaks are not managed with dpkg, for flatpacks use `flatpak list`.

Comment: The only snap I had was spotify. Clementine wasn't a snap I don't think. I just did a clean reinstall of linux and the dpkg list still only starts with programs that start with the letter "l" as in libre. Is that what everyone elses starts with? I know I have programs that start with earlier letters...?

Comment: How would I install something that starts with, say, the letter C like chrome, if the list only shows programs starting with the letter l thru z?

Comment: To install gimp, use the following command: `sudo apt update; sudo apt install gimp` To search for a package, you can do something like this: `apt-cache search gimp`

Comment: Have you tried using `dpkg -l | grep clem` to search for something like "clem" or `dpkg -l | less` to ensure that your list is not truncated (type "q" to exit `less`)?

Comment: I find this very hard to understand: "I just did **a clean reinstall of linux** and the dpkg list still only starts with programs that start with the letter "l" as in libre." Did you retain your home folder during installtion? Have you tried with a new user?

Comment: Thanks @mchid. It was a truncated list. Not sure why it was truncated, but the dpkg -l | less command solved my problem. I can see the full list now. Thanks so much!

DKBose I can see why that's confusing. I basically panicked and thought I messed somehing up and did a complete erase and reinstall only to see that I hadn't actually caused a problem, lol. Lack of sleep and stress, they'll ruin your brain I tell you wuht.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem lies in the terminal output configuration. Chances are that it is configured so that it shows **1000 lines**, while the output of `dpkg --list` or `apt list --installed` is **more than 1000 lines**.

In your terminal's preferences change the number of scrollback lines **from 1000 to 10000** and you should be able to list all of your installed programs.

Comment: Ahh so simple! Look at the preferences menu! This worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your list may be truncated depending on the type of terminal you are using or for some other reason.

Instead of using: `dpkg --list`, use the following command instead:

```
dpkg -l | less
```

You will be able to scroll up and down the list using the arrow keys.

Use the <kbd>q</kbd> key to exit the list and quit.

Alternatively, you can use `grep` to search for a particular output like in this example:

```
dpkg -l | grep clementine
```

or

```
dpkg -l | grep clemen
```

If this doesn't work, please let me know and I will delete the answer. Thanks!

---

**However, you mentioned:"*How would I install something that starts with, say, the letter C like chrome, if the list only shows programs starting with the letter l thru z?*"**. The answer is that you would use a different command to list available packages because `dpkg -l` and `dpkg --list` will only list *installed* packages.

To list *available* packages, you can use the `apt-cache search` command like in this example:

```
apt-cache search chrome
```

or

```
apt-cache search c | grep "^c"
```

Here, `"^c"` states to match results that begin with the letter c.